# Organizar elementos Android en lista

Tags: java, android, layout

Quiero realizar un pequeño diseño para un ejercicio y no consigo encontrar la manera de hacerlo correctamente.

Quiero organizar en 3 columnas de x numero de filas los elementos, digo X numero de filas porque si por ejemplo, vamos a sacar una imagen y un texto de la base de datos, la cantidad puede variar. He probado a hacerlo con 3 listview diferentes (como enseño mas abajo) pero quiero que al deslizar se deslicen las 3 columnas a la vez entonces no encuentro una manera mejor.

El diseño en sí sería algo parecido a esto (pero son 3 listviews y acabo de comentar cual es el problema en el parrafo de arriba)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: te recomiendo usar un [recyclerView con gridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-grid-layout)

Comment: Recuerda es importante agregar como lo estas realizando, de esta forma la comunidad te puede ayudar a brindarte soluciones, saludos.